# How to cast local video files from computer to TV using Google Home?

Tags: google-home, ifttt, chromecast

Okay this may be quite much, but I am trying to use Google Home to cast a video from my laptop (which I don't mind using for this sole purpose since it's old and unneeded) to my Smart LG TV which has a Chromecast.

Now I could use a Python script to search for whatever I asked google home to play on my laptop, but how exactly can I let Google Home run the script with my variables being the video file name. Is there any other solution I can use without having to buy something else? (Although I would not mind buying something to help if it were cheap)

Comment: Welcome to the site. You tagged your question with IFTTT, however, I can't find a reference to IFTTT in the question. How do you expect IFTTT to be part of this?

Comment: I was trying to find a way to use IFTTT as a sort of connection between google home and the laptop to run the python script somehow